# convert .csv with bash tools

Tags: bash, csv, sed, awk

German version of Origin [TM] saves .csv files very odd. However I have many of these .csv files and want to convert them with a script.

```
A,B
Independent variable,comment1 
"0,4","0,067"
"0,0","0,08"
"0,07","0,02"
"0,09","0,00"
```

should become

```
A,B
# Independent variable,comment1 
0.4,0.067
0.0,0.08
0.07,0.02
0.09,0.00
```

The definition of a comment by Origin seems to be

> it is the second line

Comment: How much can you guarantee about the input? First line should be untouched, second should be commented, and third+ need quotes removed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there is structure to your csv files, and Kevin's comment above is correct, then you can use [ranges by line number](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-28):

```
sed '2s/^/# /; 3,$s/"\([^,]*\),\([^,]*\)"/\1.\2/g' file
```

Or a slightly shorter way:

```
sed '2s/^/# /; 3,$s/,/./g;s/"."/,/g;s/"//g' file
```

Results:

```
A,B
# Independent variable,comment1 
0.4,0.067
0.0,0.08
0.07,0.02
0.09,0.00
```

Comment: I tried the second line. It misses the last " in a line
I added one further 's/"//g'

Comment: @JonasStein: Ahh yes there was a typo in that code, sorry about that. Please see the update. HTH.

Comment: +1 for a good solution. `2s/.*/# &/` could be the slightly briefer `2s/^/# /`.

Answer (score 2):

With sed, assuming comment lines have the word `comment`:

```
sed 's/"\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\)"/\1.\2/g;/comment/{s/^/#/}' input
```

Assuming comments follow single capital-case variable names:

```
sed 's/"\([0-9]*\),\([0-9]*\)"/\1.\2/g;/^[A-Z],/{n;s/^/#/}' inpu
```

Answer (score 2):

If you like simple solutions, here's awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{FS="\",\""; OFS=","}
NR == 2 { $0 = "# " $0 }
NR >= 3 {
   for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
      sub(/\"/,"",$i)
      sub(/,/,".",$i)
   }
}
{ print }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
A,B
# Independent variable,comment1
0.4,0.067
0.0,0.08
0.07,0.02
0.09,0.00
```

"NR" is the line number and "NF" is the number of `","`-separated fields on the current line. The rest should be obvious, I think, even if you don't know awk.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/\"//g;if($.==2){s/^/#/g;}' your_file
```

if you want to do an in place replacement:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\"//g;if($.==2){s/^/#/g;}' your_file
```

awk:

```
awk '{gsub(/\"/,"");if(NR==2)$0="#"$0;print}' your_file
```

Comment: The tricky part of the question is to replace ","s with "."s within the quoted fields but not between fields.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
awk -F\" '{$1=$1; gsub(/0,/,"0."); gsub(/ /,""); if(NR==2) printf "%s ", "#"}1' file
```